# EF core include multiple relations getting unwanted data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am a model relations as below

**Post Model**

```
public class Post : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        [Column( "user_id" )] public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual  List< Comment > Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

**User Model**

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Column( "created_at", Order = 254 )] public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        [Column( "updated_at", Order = 255 )] public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection< Post > Posts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection< Comment > Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

**Comment Model**

```
public class Comment : BaseEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        [Column( "user_id" )] public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
        [Column( "post_id" )] public int PostId { get; set; }
    }
```

And when I do this

```
public IEnumerable< Post > GetAllPosts()
        {
            return dbContext.Posts
                .Include( post => post.User )
                .ThenInclude( post => post.Comments )
                .ToList();
        }
```

I get multiple depths of data. I only need one level of child

This is my output for just a post. The data is repeating itself.

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "content": "This post is about fires going on in NSW",
        "image": null,
        "user": { 
            "firstName": "Bikram",
            "middleName": null,
            "lastName": "Bhandari",
            "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "posts": [], --I don't want this
            "comments": [  -- Unwanted
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "content": "So sad to see this",
                    "userId": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
                    "postId": 5,
                    "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "content": "Let's hope for a rain",
                    "userId": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
                    "postId": 5,
                    "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                }
            ],
            "id": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
            "userName": "bikrambhandari48@gmail.com",
            "normalizedUserName": "BIKRAMBHANDARI48@GMAIL.COM",
            "email": "bikrambhandari48@gmail.com",
            "normalizedEmail": "BIKRAMBHANDARI48@GMAIL.COM",
            "emailConfirmed": false,
            "passwordHash": "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEHBFj2Woq4/JhqyPWtaXt2xjL4+ML9XQR24pYJsvUAaAKWr/Pg4NgQ2S/O1h8fkerg==",
            "securityStamp": "XVNJKDOYMMT6SP2LLBUNHRKWGT3NZB4X",
            "concurrencyStamp": "2658eced-edd7-4458-b9e2-a010b46e3f37",
            "phoneNumber": null,
            "phoneNumberConfirmed": false,
            "twoFactorEnabled": false,
            "lockoutEnd": null,
            "lockoutEnabled": true,
            "accessFailedCount": 0
        },
        "userId": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "content": "So sad to see this",
                "user": { --Not wanted
                    "firstName": "Bikram",
                    "middleName": null,
                    "lastName": "Bhandari",
                    "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "posts": [],
                    "comments": [ --Not wanted
                        {
                            "id": 8,
                            "content": "Let's hope for a rain",
                            "userId": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
                            "postId": 5,
                            "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                            "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
                    "userName": "bikrambhandari48@gmail.com",
                    "normalizedUserName": "BIKRAMBHANDARI48@GMAIL.COM",
                    "email": "bikrambhandari48@gmail.com",
                    "normalizedEmail": "BIKRAMBHANDARI48@GMAIL.COM",
                    "emailConfirmed": false,
                    "passwordHash": "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEHBFj2Woq4/JhqyPWtaXt2xjL4+ML9XQR24pYJsvUAaAKWr/Pg4NgQ2S/O1h8fkerg==",
                    "securityStamp": "XVNJKDOYMMT6SP2LLBUNHRKWGT3NZB4X",
                    "concurrencyStamp": "2658eced-edd7-4458-b9e2-a010b46e3f37",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "phoneNumberConfirmed": false,
                    "twoFactorEnabled": false,
                    "lockoutEnd": null,
                    "lockoutEnabled": true,
                    "accessFailedCount": 0
                },
                "userId": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
                "postId": 5,
                "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
            },
            { --Not wanted
                "id": 8,
                "content": "Let's hope for a rain",
                "user": {
                    "firstName": "Bikram",
                    "middleName": null,
                    "lastName": "Bhandari",
                    "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "posts": [],
                    "comments": [
                        {
                            "id": 7,
                            "content": "So sad to see this",
                            "userId": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
                            "postId": 5,
                            "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                            "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
                        }
                    ],
                    "id": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
                    "userName": "bikrambhandari48@gmail.com",
                    "normalizedUserName": "BIKRAMBHANDARI48@GMAIL.COM",
                    "email": "bikrambhandari48@gmail.com",
                    "normalizedEmail": "BIKRAMBHANDARI48@GMAIL.COM",
                    "emailConfirmed": false,
                    "passwordHash": "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEHBFj2Woq4/JhqyPWtaXt2xjL4+ML9XQR24pYJsvUAaAKWr/Pg4NgQ2S/O1h8fkerg==",
                    "securityStamp": "XVNJKDOYMMT6SP2LLBUNHRKWGT3NZB4X",
                    "concurrencyStamp": "2658eced-edd7-4458-b9e2-a010b46e3f37",
                    "phoneNumber": null,
                    "phoneNumberConfirmed": false,
                    "twoFactorEnabled": false,
                    "lockoutEnd": null,
                    "lockoutEnabled": true,
                    "accessFailedCount": 0
                },
                "userId": "052b4889-431f-48d2-b673-5835166c03ee",
                "postId": 5,
                "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
                "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

If you see above you can see that the data are repeating itself. What am I doing wrong to retrieve all the posts and the user associated with the post and all the comments of a post? Can anybody suggest how should I define my model relations to better retrieve my data? 
I want to retrieve all the posts and comments from user's perspective too. And in the comments model, I want to know which post the comment belongs to and who is the owner of the comment too.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using Include twice instead of ThenInclude in the linq expression?

Comment: Yes I tried that too but still the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Change Tracker will fix-up releationships as it loads entities.  So if you load a Post's comments, and you have already loaded the User for some of those comments, the Navigation Property between User and Comments will be set.

> If change tracking is enabled, then when loading an entity, EF Core
>   will automatically set the navigation properties of the newly-loaded
>   entitiy to refer to any entities already loaded, and set the
>   navigation properties of the already-loaded entities to refer to the
>   newly-loaded entity.

[Loading Related Data - EF Core: Explicit Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading)

Disable Change Tracking on the DbContext to prevent this behavior,

```
public IList< Post > GetAllPosts()
{
    return dbContext.Posts.AsNoTracking()
        .Include( post => post.User )
        .ThenInclude( post => post.Comments )
        .ToList();
}
```

And return `IList<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`, otherwise your caller won't know whether this is a streaming result, and might defensively load the result into a list.

Alternatively specify the shape of the document in your JSON serializer.